# Как открыть в microsoft SQL Server Management файл с расширением .SQL как базу данных

Tags: sql

Чтобы можно было открыть таблицы и вообще он отображался в обозревателе как база данных. Сейчас он вообще никак не отображается, хоть и делал отладку и выполнял, ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выполняли скрипт, то нужно обновить ветку в браузере объектов (правая кнопка).

Да, посмотрите еще в какой базе вы выполняли скрипт. Могу предположить, что это база master.

Comment: Да, похоже что действительно выполнял в master. Но папки "таблицы" там так и не повилось( А мне как раз и нужно их открыть.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Нужно загружать базу данных и выполнять ее в своей базе данных (не в master), и нужно обновлять обозреватель. Таблицы появились)

Comment: Я думаю, что они и в master у вас есть. Обновите и удалите оттуда таблицы.

Comment: В master-е у меня почему то вообще нет такого раздела (папки) "таблицы". Но это уже не важно)